# How can i change findViewById to view binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, new-operator

Here it's my adapter code ;

```
    class ModelViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val chName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.chName)
    private val chBirthYear: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.chBirthYear)
    private val chHeight: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.chHeight)
    private val chHomeWorld: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.chHomeWorld)
```

Comment: Can you post your full adapter's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the list item view binding class and change it like this:

```
//ItemModelBinding is the generated binding class for the list view item
class ModelViewHolder(val binding: ItemModelBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: SomeModelClass) {
            binding.chName = item.chName
            binding.chBirthYear = item.chBirthYear
            binding.chHeight = item.chHeight
            binding.chHomeWorld= item.chHomeWorld
            
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
```

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ModelViewHolder(view: View) RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val binding = LayoutYouWantToUseBinding.bind(view)
}
```

Comment: ViewHolders have to subclass ViewHolder. What view would you pass to this constructor?

Comment: Would love to give more explanation but with the question being "here is my code, how can I change it to view binding" I think it would just be random noise as I think the code in my answer is pretty much exactly the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

**ListAdapter** is RecyclerView.Adapter base class for presenting List data in a RecyclerView, including computing diffs between Lists on a *background thread*.

**DiffUtil** helps in computing the difference between two lists on a background thread. and only update the view for which data has been changed means less number of call of **onBindViewHolder()** which would have called for all the item if we still stick with **notifyDataSetChanged()** on any data change.

```
class ModelAdapter : ListAdapter<Model, ModelAdapter.ModelViewHolder>(ModelDiffCallBack()) {

    class ModelViewHolder(private val binding: ModelItemLayoutBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(model: Model) {
        //if data binding is also enabled
        binding.model = model
        //else set data for each view one after another
        binding.txtTitle.text = model.title
        //and so on for all the items
        
        
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ModelViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ModelItemLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return ModelViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ModelViewHolder =
    ModelViewHolder.from(parent)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ModelViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val model = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(model)
}

class ModelDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Model>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Model, newItem: Model): Boolean =
        oldItem === newItem

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Model, newItem: Model): Boolean =
        oldItem == newItem
}

}
```